# Modify column type and replace data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL server 2008 R2 with 100 Million records.

One of the column is a foreign key to another table.

```
Table Student 
ID   Name    AccessToLap
1    Mike    1

Table AccessType
ID   Name
1    Allow
2    Deny
```

How can i change the column `AccessToLab` from `int` to `varchar` and change the values from `1` to `Allow` and from `2` to `Deny` without dropping and recreating the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alter table Student add AccessType varchar(50);

update  s
set     AccessType = at.Name
from    Student s
join    AccessType at
on      at.ID = s.AccessToLap;

alter table Student drop column AccessToLap;

exec sp_rename 'Student.AccessType', 'AccessToLap', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: and... EXEC sp_rename 'Student.AccessType', 'AccessToLap', 'COLUMN'

Comment: why are you renaming the column?

Comment: The query adds a new column (AccessType) which is temporary.  It updates the column to the right values using the old column (AccessToLap.)  At the end, it drops the old column and renames the new column.